# jbpm6 This request requires HTTP authentication

Tags: rest, jboss, jbpm

Every transaction I make through RemoteRuntimeEngine

```
RemoteRestRuntimeFactory factory = new RemoteRestRuntimeFactory(deploymentId, new URL(url), user, psw);
RemoteRuntimeEngine engine = factory.newRuntimeEngine();
TaskService taskService = engine.getTaskService();
List<TaskSummary> tasks = taskService.getTasksOwned(user, "en-UK");
```

Throws me an Error invoking GetTasksOwnedCommand via REST

JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1 - JBWEB000064: Error report

## JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 401 - Validation fails.

**JBWEB000309: type** JBWEB000067: Status report

**JBWEB000068: message** Validation fails.

**JBWEB000069: description** JBWEB000121: This request requires HTTP authentication.

#### JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1

My Stacktrace

```
at org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject.executeRestCommand(AbstractRemoteCommandObject.java:342)
13:26:38,851 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject.execute(AbstractRemoteCommandObject.java:110)
13:26:38,851 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.jbpm.services.task.impl.command.CommandBasedTaskService.getTasksOwned(CommandBasedTaskService.java:194)
13:26:38,852 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at com.redhat.gss.SearchTasksServlet.doPost(SearchTasksServlet.java:36)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of jBPM are you using? You need to make sure that the client is using the same version as the server. 
Does the user and password are correct? can you login via the UI?

Comment: In my server was 6.0.2redhat-6 version, so I changed to that version in my pom.xml and I'm facing org.kie.services.client.api.command.exception.RemoteCommunicationException: The remote server requires form-based authentication.

Comment: I've resolved my dependencies removing my ear project and leaving a web project that depends on ejb project, Maybe you could provide a full example with an ear having a web and ejb project.

Comment: I would love to have time to do such example, but it will not happen soon, so let us know if we can assist you further

Comment: No problem I really appreciate your time.